# Is it better to pass an entire dataframe to a function, or create a dataframe that contains only the columns I will use in that function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I'm currently developing a function that uses 2 columns of a dataframe to perform calculations. I was wondering whether it would be better (in terms of speed) to create a smaller dataframe,with only the 2 columns involved and pass that to the function or if it would still be okay to pass the entire dataframe.

```
df=Datareader('file')
finaldf=Calc_funct(df)
```

or

```
df=Datareader('file')

small_df=df[['cpdnm', 'smiles']]

finaldf=Calc_funct(df)
```

The dataframe is made up of around 5k rows and 20 columns and even after some tests I can't decide whether it is actually better to pass a smaller dataframe. (in the future this function will be used on much larger samples and therefore I would like to understand which is the best option)

(pandas V2.2.0)

Update:
(I'll have to be a bit generic with the variable names but I hope you understand)
now im passing the smaller df that contain just 2 column ['name','id'].
the function converts the df['name'] of all the lines into another format via an external function, and if the name is not available it calls another function to obtain it from the df['id'] field, and converts it to the final format. after each conversion they are added to a list (in theory it is faster in this case than return a series/df and is better for the future uses of this functions)

Comment: It depends of what you do inside the function and what you do with the result ?
It may be too costly to copy the very large dataframe and/or too costly to process it.
can you give more details ?

and if the result will be added in a column of the original dataframe.
It could be good to check and use:  pandas.DataFrame.apply
which is made to apply a function to many rows of a large dataframe.

Comment: When you call *Calc_funct(df)* you do **not** send the entire content of the Dataframe to the function - it's just a reference. Therefore the overhead is trivial

Comment: There is no difference in cost for passing one dataframe or the other. You are *creating* overhead by defining `small_df` in the first place.